# How to handle null fields on firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I load data from firebase to my form page. The first time, database is empty. After user fill the form and click button then data is saved. then user again go to the form page if user enter some data, these data loaded from firebase. but some data can be ignore to the fill. when load these data i got error. becuase these data not in the firebase.(no fields)

```
  factory ProfileModel.fromForestore(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    Map data = doc.data;

   return ProfileModel(
      coverPhotoNames: data['businessDetails']['photos']['coverPhotos'],
      profilePhoto: data['businessDetails']['photos']['profilePhoto'],
      displayName: data['displayName'],
      description: data['businessDetails']['description'],
      notes: data['businessDetails']['notes'],
      addressline1: data['businessDetails']['addressline1'],
      addressline2: data['businessDetails']['addressline2'],
      addressline3: data['businessDetails']['addressline3'],
      location: data['businessDetails']['location'],
      website: data['businessDetails']['website'],
      primaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['primaryContactNo'],
      workphone: data['businessDetails']['workphone'],
      secondaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['secondaryContactNo'],
      openingHours: data['businessDetails']['openingHours']
```

> E/flutter ( 5436): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on
>   null. E/flutter ( 5436): Receiver: null E/flutter ( 5436): Tried
>   calling:

I added this way, but not working because ['photos'] also null

```
data['businessDetails']['photos']['coverPhotos'] ?? [],
```

how to handle this kind of error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

find out what data can be fill with nullable on your form..

for ex:= user can select / deselect photos.

so, change your model class like this,

```
if(data['businessDetails']['photos'] != null)
  return ProfileModel(
      coverPhotoNames: data['businessDetails']['photos']['coverPhotos'],
      profilePhotoName: data['businessDetails']['photos']['profilePhoto'],
      displayName: data['displayName'],
      description: data['businessDetails']['description'],
      notes: data['businessDetails']['notes'],
      addressline1: data['businessDetails']['addressline1'],
      addressline2: data['businessDetails']['addressline2'],
      addressline3: data['businessDetails']['addressline3'],
      location: data['businessDetails']['location'],
      website: data['businessDetails']['website'],
      primaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['primaryContactNo'],
      workphone: data['businessDetails']['workphone'],
      secondaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['secondaryContactNo'],
      openingHours: data['businessDetails']['openingHours']
  );
else //without photos
return ProfileModel(
  displayName: data['displayName'],
  description: data['businessDetails']['description'],
  notes: data['businessDetails']['notes'],
  addressline1: data['businessDetails']['addressline1'],
  addressline2: data['businessDetails']['addressline2'],
  addressline3: data['businessDetails']['addressline3'],
  location: data['businessDetails']['location'],
  website: data['businessDetails']['website'],
  primaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['primaryContactNo'],
  workphone: data['businessDetails']['workphone'],
  secondaryContactNo: data['businessDetails']['secondaryContactNo'],
  openingHours: data['businessDetails']['openingHours']
);
```